# What does stdin mean in Python Errors?

Tags: python, exception, stdin, traceback

When I get a syntax error for example, I get this block of text:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
    while True print('Hello world')
        while True print('Hello world')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I did some research and I found out there are three standard streams.

"The three I/O connections are called standard input (stdin), standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr)."

So why isn't this standard error?

Comment: Briefly: the error message isn't telling you where the error message was sent, it's telling you where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` needs a colon (:).  You're getting an error at `stdin` because you're typing the script on the command line, and python (the `python` command you are entering text into) is reading it from it's `stdin` stream (i.e. the terminal).  You typed an error into Python's `stdin` and it's telling you that.

```
while True:
    print('Hello world')
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the source of the code is stdin, e.g. it was typed in at a console.